# exit button event in phonegap for iOS?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

is there any event Listener that calls when we press on iPhone close button in phonegap?

so that we can do final task when application close.

i have found that onunload method will call when webpage redirect but it want work here.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `PhoneGapDelegate.m` class, you have the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, replacing from iOS 4+ the `applicationWillTerminate` method for applications supporting background execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to Phonegap's "pause" event:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

Comment: This tracks the user switching from the app, but it does not track the app being closed (it continues to run after that switch).