# Does Ionic 5 call ngOnDestroy for Services and home page when app is closed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, ngondestroy

In my Ionic 5 project, I have `ngOnDestroy()` for the service classes to clean up data. I also have `ngOnDestroy()` on my Home page. When I do the following navigation from the Home page to Page A and back to the Home page the `ngOnDestroy()` for Page A is triggering.

```
 - Home page -> Page A 
      
 - Home page <- Page A
```

The issue is when I close the app I am expecting the `ngOnDestroy()` on the Home page and all the service classes to be triggered but that is not happening. I see the following is mentioned in the Ionic documentation.

> ngOnDestroy will only fire when a page "popped".

I checked that even `ionViewWillLeave` is not triggering on Home page when the app is closed. Please suggest how do I do clean-up activity in the Home page and services?

Comment: Use background mode:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can use, for websites, the window [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) but it is not reliably fired.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409538/how-to-catch-exit-app-event)  answers also recommend using beforeunload in cordova when you run inside an app.